# LSTM Seq2Seq model accuracy stuck at ~80%

Tags: python, keras, nlp, lstm, seq2seq

I am training an LSTM Seq2Seq model to solve an address parsing problem. The problem entails taking an initial address string (such as "184 Park Ave, NYC, NY") and breaking it into its individual components: {number: 184, street: Park Ave, city: NYC, region: NY}.

I am using an LSTM model to take in character embedded sequences (length=80) of the initial address string and output a sequence of individual address components (length=153). My vocabulary size is 41. Each character, number, or special character is mapped to a numerical value between 0 and 41 including spaces.

Below I have attached the code to retrieve the training and testing datasets:

```
test1 = list()
train2 = list()
test2 = list()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = np.load("X_train.npy"), np.load("X_test.npy"), np.load("y_train.npy"), np.load("y_test.npy"),  

with tensorflow.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  for seq1, seq2, seq3, seq4 in zip(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test): 
    train1.append(to_categorical(seq1, num_classes=40+1))
    test1.append(to_categorical(seq3, num_classes=40+1))
    train2.append(to_categorical(seq2, num_classes=40+1))
    test2.append(to_categorical(seq4, num_classes=40+1))

train1, test1, train2, test2 = np.array(train1), np.array(test1), np.array(train2), np.array(test2)

print(train1.shape, test1.shape, train2.shape, test2.shape)
```

-> (100000, 80, 41) (100000, 80, 41) (100000, 153, 41) (100000, 153, 41)

When training the model on these sequences, I reach a training accuracy of **~80%** after about 10,000 examples and the model suddenly stop improving. Below is the code for my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(n_in_seq_length, 41)))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_out_seq_length))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(RepeatVector(n_out_seq_length))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(41, activation='softmax')))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())

with tensorflow.device('/device:GPU:0'):
  model.fit(train1, train2, epochs=1, batch_size=n_batch)
```

I have tried GRUs and Vanilla RNNs along with various model architectures and number of hidden layers but nothing seems to improve performance. My goal is to train the model to around **95%** accuracy. How do I improve my model's training accuracy?

Any feedback would be much appreciated. Thank you!

**------------------Edit--------------------**

The dataset files are located at: [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1onv-NUY_8Lx0v--YKXAFh5IrQlNSCLSN?usp=sharing)

Comment: This was one of the most innovative uses of LSTM I've ever seen! Please add a toy dataset we can give it a try :)

Comment: I added a dataset to the answer. Would really appreciate if you can try it out and let me know your findings :)

Comment: Silly question for you: have you looked at using something like autokeras to evolve a nn for you? How is the project going? I have been trying to use a spacy based approach which isnt working very well..

Comment: I am looking at some autoencoders but the common solution is to use seq2seq models like the one mentioned above including some attention mechnisms. I would really appreciate any suggestions on how to debug the model and increase its accuracy. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at https://deepparse.org/..